# Outlook Class Library in vb.net - Weird freezes when using Messagebox

Tags: vb.net, outlook, messagebox, freeze

I have encountered a rather weired behaviour with my plug-in I'm writing for Outlook 2003 (vb.NET 4.0, WinXP SP3, Visual Studio 2010).

I'm opening a setup window (Windows Form) via a menu. Besides changing the user settings it is also possible to click a button to call a function which imports a XML file from a remote server.

This function doesn't do much else than deleting the old file from the local folder and copying the new file from the server using My.Computer.FileSystem methods.

Now comes the weired part: When the file has been successfully copied, a messagebox will be displayed to inform the user. From the moment it is being closed, both Outlook and the setup window freeze, but not completely as you can still use the keyboard to close the setup form for example. It just doesn't react to the mouse anymore. If I close the setup form via keyboard I also get the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error from the function that has been calling the form (it immediately goes to error processing after the form is closed). Outlook stays frozen and I have to terminate the process then.

Additional things I noticed:

1.) If the new XML file has not been copied and the function is terminated earlier (i. e. because the current version is already present or the server is not available), the resulting messageboxes never freeze the program.

2.) Moving the messagebox in question from the function to the button click event of the form doesn't change anything.

3.) Removing the messagebox solves the problem. But the next messagebox created by the setup form will result in the same error.

4.) Replacing the usual System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox with the WPF System.Windows.MessageBox also solves the problem. The MsgBox function causes the same fault, though.

5.) In Outlook I can still browse the folders via mouse but I can't access the menu bar or the buttons and I also can't close the window with "X".

6.) If the new file is invalid, it will be deleted and the old file will be renamed. In this case, two messages will be displayed and this time the program only freezes if the button is clicked a second time and after the last (4th) messagebox has been closed. If the setup form is closed and re-opened between the two clicks everything keeps working normal. Also, Outlook itself can be used normally after the setup form is closed (it doesn't freeze the menus/buttons).

7.) This happens in debug mode but also in normal mode.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: MessageBox displays a modal dialog that disables the other windows.  Sounds like they don't get re-enabled.  Typical kind of problem when you ab/use threads.

Comment: I'm not using any additional threads. It's just a windows form that displays message boxes. I've also encountered this problem with a different form just recently but it's the first time this has happened with that one...